# How can I ensure that the my database does not allow INSERTs past a certain timestamp?

Tags: ios, mysql, node.js, database-design

I am building an auctioning app for iOS, using node.js for the server code, and using MySQL for the database.

For a given item, when a new higher bid comes in, I store the timestamp, and there is 24 hours for another bid to come in and beat that bid. If 24 hours passes and no one puts in a higher bid, the item is sold.

What is the best approach to enforcing this logic?

In my calls to pull all items down to the client, I am retrieving the timestamp, so I could block INSERTs past this timestamp+24 hours from the client side, but if someone had stale data this may not be reliable, and Inserts could still happen.

Should I check on the server every time someone tries to insert, and see if that timestamp and NOW() are greater than 24 hours apart? And would this entail making a SELECT call first to check the timestamp and then making the INSERT call if it should be allowed?

Or should I let people update the database and I search the database for the first bid that doesn't have another bid for at least 24 hours after?

Comment: Your node app should validate the incoming request.

Comment: Which kind of error are you more comfortable with: bids getting rejected when they shouldn't, or bids getting in that shouldn't?  Since you have a remedy for the latter but not the former, seems an easy call to make.

Comment: You should be able to use a BEFORE INSERT trigger to generate an error if such an insert is attempted; or it could still allow the insert but (with an additional field added to the table) flag it as past the cutoff.

Comment: That's an application problem that needs to be solved in the API you provide.